# Exterior wiring for 6 RV camping spots

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm starting from scratch. I have temporary power now. I have a building I'm putting up but I want to put in 6 RV camping spots each with 50 amp service plus a couple regular outlets for each site.  What wire should I purchase, what do I need for a service station box?  If someone can walk me through it, I'll still want to hire an electrician but at least I'll have some knowledge of what I need and try and figure a budget.

Comment: What distance are you talking/thinking about to the spots?  From one centre power point you are thinking of probably 4 or 2 gauge AL wire(cheaper than copper).  About 400 amp service.  I would check with local power company what they can supply first at the site, a RV park not usually near easy power unless lucky.

Comment: So the main barn I am putting up is about 150' away from the meter.  From the barn to first spot is 50' and 2nd spot is basically back to back with the first site.  Then 2 more back to back sites is 50' away.  The next 2 are 100' away and if I can swing it, 2 more would be another 100'.

Comment: The feedback on here is awesome,  thanks for your input.  I'll study what everyone is telling me, I'll digest it, but I promise I'll understand it once I study it.  I'll continue to take all the advice I can get.   I want to spread out my sites so no one is on top of another and everyone will have a wonderful view of the middle of the forest I'm in and watch the deer every morning with some coffee.   I have a vision and would love to let other people enjoy this awesome spot about 40 minutes from downtown Nashville.

Answer (score 6):

### Count the sites.

You start by looking at the possible parking spots for RVs, and the electrical power stands servicing those.  Let's assume a *worst case scenario* of every RV being plugged into the highest power socket it can reach.

> *Example: say you have 3 RV power stands, all 20A/30A/50A, but there are five RV parking spots, so five RVs could reach those 3 stands.  So your worst-case scenario is three RVs using the 50A sockets, and two RVs using the 30A sockets, and you don't count any 20A sockets at all.  Get it?*

- You take the number of 50A sockets and multiply by 12,000 VA.
- You take the number of 30A "TT30" sockets *in this worst-case* and multiply by 3600 VA.
- You take the number of 20A/120V outlets and multiply by 2400 VA. Remember, assign only one outlet per RV parking spot.

For example, six 50A sockets (as your worst case) is 12,000 x 6 = 72,000 VA.  *That sounds like a lot!*

### A favorable derate for multiple sites.

[image]

Now, you take the number of RV spaces and look at NEC Table 551.73(A).  That gives you a "favorable derate". For instance, according to the table, 6 RV sites takes a 60% derate. You multiply the above VA with that derate number. **E.G. in your case, 72,000 VA x 60% = 43,200 VA**.  That is the amount of power you need to provision to the site.

Divide by 240V to get amps - 180 amps.

I can say full-throated that "4/0 aluminum" is the right feeder for the job, since that is exactly its native rating.    And, you can use any common-as-dirt 200A service panel for distribution to individual RV sites.

Now, if your distance from supply to RV stands is over about 160 feet, I would encourage you to think about *voltage drop* and maybe upsize that feeder. 4/0 is the largest '/ought' designation; the next larger size is 250 kcmil, and it goes up by 50s and 100s from there - 300, 350, 400, 500 etc.  Although too large and the wire won't fit on panel lugs.

All wires mentioned are aluminum; the panel lugs are aluminum and at these sizes, copper simply makes no sense. Any pro electrician who takes a % markup on the wire will strongly encourage copper, though.

### Splitting to save home-runs

If your site layout favors a location supporting two RVs, that'd be 100A for two RVs, then our friend Table 551.73(A) says two sites get a 90% derate so the feeder is 90A.  That is happily the rating of the very popular/common "2-2-2-4" wire size, commonly used in manufactured-home parks.

A single stand takes a 100% derate and needs 50A wire - that #6 copper UF*, #8 *any copperwire but UF*, or #6 aluminum.

### Typical RV panels at the site

["RV Pedestal" subpanels are commonly sold](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Power-Distribution-Temporary-Power-Disconnects-RV-Electrical-Panels/100-amp/N-5yc1vZc9iwZ1z1cklu) and fitted at RV stands. Some are made for direct burial, to save you mounting a pole.  Those contain any varierty of 50A, 30A and/or 20A "GFCI" socket. Having all 3 sockets allows them to serve any type of RV.  Further, these often allow "daisy-chaining" so you may be able to power 2 stands by running 2-2-2-4 to one RV stand box, then down and onward to the next one, with the run fed from a 90A breaker. Saves you a home-run.

You don't need to use these commercially made pre-assembled panels; you just aren't likely to get such an elegant solution trying to knock it together out of panels, breakers and outdoor outlets.   Remember RVs need the quality $80 Hubbell sockets, because they're used every day. The $30 el-cheap-o's are for ranges where they're unplugged once every 20 years. Ask an EVer about that!

On these "RV subpanels", as long as they serve only one space, *you only need to calculate load based on ONE socket being used at once*. And that is the normal way to do that thing.  Thus you allocate 12,000 VA (50A) to an RV stand that contains 50A, 30A and 20A sockets, or 90A to two of them.

---

---

---

* or #6 NM "Romex", but that is not allowed outdoors, so it's never a player in RV stand wiring.

Comment: I have the room to keep going g with more spots in my little forest.  Eventually add up to 20 spots.  Each site will have 2 rv spots facing opposite directions so each site has their awning opposite from each other and has a view and keeping it private.   Thanks for your input

Comment: 20 spots, you are at 45% so you need 450A. Note the rule also applies *per load center/panel*, so a 200A panel can support seven sites (50 x 7 x 55%).  As such the easiest way to build 20 sites would be three 200A panels, and they offer "600A" residential service that should satisfy that fine.   Note that EV charging takes more, and is excluded from the favorable derate. 17 RV spots + 3 EV spots is 17 x 50 x 47% + 3 x 50 x 100%.  But for EV charging, use "power sharing" or "grid limit" features in smarter EVSEs.  With grid limit, EVs don't count at all :)